# how to change the thumbnails' (icons) default size in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, thumbnails

In Windows 7 I used to set my preferred thumbnail size:

[image: set thumbnail size windows 10]

Then I go in *Folder options* and make sure that the current style would apply to all folders of the same type:

[image: apply to all folders windows 10]

However, that no longer works. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Window 10, go to the `view` option on the top -

[image: View option]

Click on the preferred thumbnail size -

[image: thumbnail size]

Next click on the `Change folder and search options` like shown on the right hand side -

[image: Folder options]

On the `View` tab in the subsequent panel, click on `Apply to folders`. It will prompt you to confirm that you want the view settings of the current folder (with the applied `thumbnail view` change) applied to all folders. Click on `yes`.

[image: Apply to folders]

Now all folders will have the same `thumbnail size` as the one in your current folder, which you had changed in the second step.
Works fine on`Windows 10`.

Comment: so you just repeated what i am saying no longer works? :P

Comment: Ah,  I imagined you tried in Windows 7, and were not aware of how to do it in 10. What exactly is it that is not working after these steps? Which version of `Windows 10` are you running? Did you happen to navigate to any other folder before applying the change to all folders?

Comment: The default view does not change. A newly opened folder of the same type still displays with the old icon size. Windows 10 Pro 1903. No I did not navigate to other folders before applying.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with `1903`, commonly reported. In case you haven't tried it already, do give a look here - https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/135064-1903-update-all-folders-set-back-default-cant-customize-them.html